# Electron - copy file from extraFiles on desktop when an event occur

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, file-copying, asar

I have a python script that is copied with all the needed electron files during the build process using the extra files configuration. I need to get the file and copy it on the desktop when some operations are done by users, but due to a permission issue windows will prevent this to occur.

Is there a way to copy the file when needed?